# Как распаковать бинарный файл в список?

Tags: python, list, numpy, структуры-данных

Есть файл, содержащий комплексные числа.

У меня получается распаковать его в `numpy.array`, а я хочу в список, т.к. количество чисел изначально неизвестно, а массиву в отличии от списка нужно задавать размерность сразу.

Пытаюсь использовать код:

```
data[x,y]= complex(struct.unpack('f', f.read(4))[0], 
                        struct.unpack('f', f.read(4))[0])
```

Код работает для `np.array`, если пытаюсь использовать со списком, то выдает ошибку:

> list indices must be integers, not tuple

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы не воспользоваться Numpy и для записи и для чтения комплексных чисел?

Пример с комплексным вектором:

```
In [75]: A1 = np.array([1+2j, 1-2j], dtype='complex128')

In [76]: A1
Out[76]: array([1.+2.j, 1.-2.j])

In [77]: np.savetxt('d:/temp/A1.txt', A1.view('float'))

In [78]: B1 = np.loadtxt('d:/temp/A1.txt').view('complex')

In [79]: B1
Out[79]: array([1.+2.j, 1.-2.j])

In [80]: A1 == B1
Out[80]: array([ True,  True])
```

Пример с комплексной 2D матрицей:

```
In [81]: A2 = np.array(
    ...:     [[1+2j, 1-2j],
    ...:      [2+3j, 2-3j]], dtype='complex128')
    ...:
    ...:

In [82]: np.savetxt('d:/temp/A2.txt', A2.view('float'))

In [83]: B2 = np.loadtxt('d:/temp/A2.txt').view('complex')

In [84]: B2
Out[84]:
array([[1.+2.j, 1.-2.j],
       [2.+3.j, 2.-3.j]])

In [85]: A2 == B2
Out[85]:
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]])
```

Comment: У меня есть несколько файлов, открываю поочередно, в каждом прочитываю синхрослова и шапки, если шапка подходит, то перекладываю комплексные числа из под шапки в массив. проблема в том, что я не знаю заранее сколько будет комплексных чисел и не могу заранее создать массив. А сохранять в текст и потом прочитывать по моему не особенно рационально в моей ситуации

Comment: @lampochki, тогда попробуйте читать по одному "синхрослову" пока читается...